A probability problem involving no replacement
Question:
There are 6 identical balls, numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Three balls are drawn successively without replacement. Let m be the average of the numbers on the first two balls drawn, and let n be the average of the numbers on the three balls drawn. What is the probability that the absolute difference between m and n is no more than 1/2? _________

The thought process of manual calculation is as follows:


My attempt of two methods to solve this problem using code:
allCs = Permutations[Range[6], {3}];
sC = Select[allCs, Abs[Mean[#[[1 ;; 2]]] - Mean[#]] <= 1/2 &];
p = Length[sC]/Length[allCs]

allCs = Permutations[Range[6], {3}]
mValues = Mean /@ allCs[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
nValues = Mean /@ allCs;
sC = Pick[allCs, UnitStep[1/2 - Abs[mValues - nValues]], 1];
p = Length[sC]/Length[allCs]

Is there a better way to solve this probability problem?

What are the characteristics of a "better way" ?  Is there some generalization that is of interest?  Larger number of balls?  Larger sample size?  Most compact?  Fastest?

Instead of constructing a new list, it's faster to just count the elements that satisfy a criterion:
Count[allCs, x_ /; Abs[Mean[x[[1 ;; 2]]] - Mean[x]] <= 1/2] / Length[allCs]
(*    7/15    *)

Similarly, counting elements by the truth value of the comparison,
CountsBy[allCs, Abs[Mean[#[[1 ;; 2]]] - Mean[#]] <= 1/2 &]
(*    <|True -> 56, False -> 64|>    *)
%[True]/Total[%]
(*    7/15    *)


Here is an approach using only Mathematica functions for probability theory:
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[Range[6]];
Probability[
 Abs[Mean[{x1, x2}] - Mean[{x1, x2, x3}]] <= 1/2 \[Conditioned] x1 != x2 != x3, 
 {x1 \[Distributed] dist, x2 \[Distributed] dist, x3 \[Distributed] dist}]
(* 7/15 *)

The urn with balls is represented with EmpiricalDistribution[Range[6]], and the non-replacement condition with x1 != x2 != x3.
If the replacement is allowed, the result is.
Probability[
 Abs[Mean[{x1, x2}] - Mean[{x1, x2, x3}]] <= 1/2, 
 {x1 \[Distributed] dist, x2 \[Distributed] dist, x3 \[Distributed] dist}]
(* 5/9 *)

